# Compile Error Opening Workbook in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a code that I am running that is stored in ThisWorkbook. It was originally Private Sub Workbook_Activate and Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate. This was causing some unexpected results when switching between open workbooks. So I have changed the code to what is below. Only now, I get a compile error message (the Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose is highlighted when I get this error message) that says:

Compile error:

Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

I am not savvy enough in VBA to understand this error message or a good fix for it. All help and suggestions are welcome.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call AddToCellMenu
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu
    Call DeletePopUpMenu
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
```

The Cancel parameter is there to let you prevent the workbook from closing - e.g. if certain conditions haven't been met. Setting Cancel to True stops the workbook from closing - see the [Workbook.BeforeClose documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194765.aspx)

Comment: Thanks barrowc. I have left work for the day and will try that in the morning. If this works, I will give you the green checkmark. In the meantime, is there anything that should be added to the Workbook_Open as well?

Comment: [Workbook.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196215.aspx) doesn't take any parameters so no need to change that one

Comment: Thanks again barrowc. Made the suggested changes and all worked as required. Appreciate the assistance!